# How to limit a Twitter search to specific accounts in R

Tags: r, twitter

here's my code:

```
    library(RCurl)
    library(twitteR)
    library(ROAuth)
    #run the libraries ctrl+r
    api_key<-"3snovyV8bNn8jVWu93UNP61rd"
    api_secret<-"1U3crdPY2kS4Nx12OaxjlE2geyDFSzJXJnVSJaEvIUV3LqHdCa"
    access_token<-"2457340967-8wOYs9X7m66RzywCtT6KHlow6hP8zTNpSMTid7Y"
    access_token_secret<-"gTqLbHGPayMgF3FG0o0tb42yBWd3TiCZ67vhXOfnLICZT"
    setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
    #ctrl+r
    searchTwitter("Cristiano Ronaldo", n=25, lang="en", since=NULL, 
    until=NULL,
          locale=NULL, geocode=NULL, sinceID=NULL, maxID=NULL,
          resultType=NULL, retryOnRateLimit=120)
    #ctrl+r
    Rtweets(n=25, lang="en", since=NULL)
```

I'm looking for a command in order to specify the tweets I want to extract by account (i.e. Cristiano Ronaldo's official Twitter account).

Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to to the Stack Overflow community! As a general principle, try not to post any access tokens with your question lest someone decides to use them to questionable ends.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the smappR package's function `getTimeline` to get tweets from a single user account.

You'll need to install smappR from GitHub, if you haven't done so previously.

`library(devtools)
install_github("SMAPPNYU/smappR")`

You could then use the `getTimeline` function to get Ronaldo's tweets:

```
getTimeline(screen_name = "Cristiano",
filename = "ronaldo_tweets.json", # where tweets will be stored
n=500, ## number of tweets to download (max is 3,200)
oauth_folder = "~/Dropbox/credentials")
```

The `screen_name` argument refers to the user's twitter handle. Note also that smappR assumes that you have one or more OAuth objects in a folder. You can read about their setup here: https://github.com/SMAPPNYU/smappR

I hope that this helps.